Which countries have an agreement with the US that specifically exempts dual nationals from induction into the US military in the event of a draft?
I was reading the "Dual Nationals" section on Selective Service System's website, found here. It states that some dual nationals would be exempt from induction into the military in the event of the draft and lists the exemption below:
"a dual national whose other country of nationality has an agreement with the U.S. which specifically provides for an exemption"
I cannot find information on these agreements anywhere. How would I find if my country is one such, or better yet, do you know of a list of all such countries?

I think this question is better suited for the politics SE.

I believe it's a situation with the Compact of Free Association states: Marshall Islands, Federated States of Micronesia, and Palau. While they are sovereign countries, their citizens have broad rights to live and reside in the US, and when they do, they are subject to the draft.

@uberhaxed This would likely be closed on politics as it is about a law rather then about politics or the political process.

@user71659 illegal aliens are also subject to the draft.

The list of countries whose dual nationals are exempt from the draft was available on the Selective Service System's website until 2015, when it was removed. The webpage with the list says it was last updated on April 12, 2006. According to this page, dual nationals of the USA and one of the following countries were class 4-C exempt in 2006:

Australia, Austria, Bahamas, Barbados, Belgium, Botswana, Brazil,
Burma, Colombia, Cuba, Curaçao, Cyprus, El Salvador, Fiji, Finland,
Gambia, Ghana, Grenada, Guyana, India, Indonesia, Jamaica, Kenya,
Kiribati, Lesotho, Malawi, Malaysia, Malta, Mauritania, Mauritius,
Nauru, Netherlands, Niger, Nigeria, "Norfolk Islands", Norway,
Pakistan, Papua New Guinea, Saint Lucia, Seychelles, Sierra Leone,
Singapore, Solomon Islands, South Africa, Sri Lanka, Suriname,
Swaziland, Sweden, Switzerland, Tonga, Trinidad and Tobago, Tuvalu,
United Kingdom, Zambia.

 Note: Curaçao and Norfolk Island are non-sovereign dependencies of respectively the Netherlands and Australia that do not issue their own passports. 
No sources are given for the bilateral agreements on which this list is based. In addition, a similar draft exemption (4-T) exists for non-citizen US residents from certain countries, as non-citizen residents are also sometimes required to register depending on their visa status. In 2006, this exemption applied to nationals of the following countries:

Argentina, Austria, Costa Rica, Estonia, Honduras, Ireland, Italy, Latvia, Liberia, Norway, Paraguay, Spain, Switzerland, Taiwan, Yugoslavia.

Note: While the list dates from 2006, Yugoslavia ceased to exist in 2003.
The page also lists the countries whose citizens are eligible for a 4-A-A exemption, for those who completed at least 12 months of military service in a foreign nation. In 2006, this was

Argentina, Australia, Belgium, Bolivia, Brazil, Canada, Chile, Colombia, Costa Rica, Denmark, Dominican Republic, Ecuador, El Salvador, France, Federal Republic of Germany, Greece, Guatemala, Haiti, Honduras, Iceland, Italy, Japan (service prior to 1980), South Korea, Luxembourg, Mexico, Netherlands, New Zealand, Nicaragua, Norway, Pakistan, Panama, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Portugal, Taiwan, Thailand, Trinidad and Tobago, Turkey, United Kingdom, Uruguay, Venezuela.

I was unable to find a list more recent than 2006 on the internet. Since the exemptions are based on bilateral agreements between the US and foreign countries, the current lists are likely similar. Finally, it is important to note that dual nationals and foreign nationals eligible for a draft exemption are still required to register for the draft normally.
If you are a US dual national and would like to have more up to date information, it may be worthwhile to contact the SSS directly.
